# Is there an ATagAfterWrap instead of ATagBeforeWrap or a wrapSubAndItem insted of wrapItemAndSub?

Tags: typo3, typoscript

First of all I'm total newbie when it comes to Typoscript and just supposed to make some css adjustments to a page. However there is a small adjustment I'd like to make. Instead of this (the mentioned ATagBeforeWrap is used in this context):

```
<menulvl1>
    <li>
       <a>Menu-Lvl 1 Link</a>
       <submenu>
          <!--.... -->
       </submenu>
    </li>
</menulvl1>
```

Without ATagBeforeWrap (or set to 0), I read I would get this:

```
 <li>
    <a>
        <submenu>
          <!--.... -->
       </submenu>
    </a>

 </li>
```

But what I want is this:

```
<li>    
    <submenu></submenu>
    <a>Menu-Lvl 1Link</a>
</li>
```

**EDIT:**
This is the typoscript responsible for the rendering. Sorry for the mass of code:

```
# Copy basic menu object from TS template 'menu' so we don't have to repeat all that

#lib.menu.level2.wrap = TEXT

menu.top < menu.defaults
menu.top {
  # Also show pages which have not-in-menu flag set in page properties
  includeNotInMenu = 0

  # Create a menu out of the pages specifically listed under special.value
  special = directory
  special.value = {$menu.top.pages}

  entryLevel = 0

  1 {
    expAll = 1
    wrap = <ul class="layer1">|</ul>
    NO {
      doNotShowLink = 0
      wrapItemAndSub = <li class="first">|</li>|*|<li>|</li>|*|<li class="last">|</li>
      ATagParams = class="layer1"
    }
    ACT{
        wrapItemAndSub = <li class="first selected">|</li>|*|<li class="selected">|</li>|*|<li class="last selected">|</li>
        ATagParams = class="layer1 active"
    }
    IFSUB < .NO
    IFSUB.ATagParams = class="layer1"
    CUR < .ACT
    CUR.ATagParams = class="layer1 selected"
    CURIFSUB < .ACT
    CURIFSUB.ATagParams = class="layer1 selected"
  }

  2 < .1

  2.wrap(
    <div class="layer2" style="display:none;">
        <div class="inner-wrapper">
  )
  #2.wrap.insertData = 1

  2.NO.doNotLinkIt = 1
  2.ACT.doNotLinkIt = 1
  2.IFSUB.doNotLinkIt = 1
  2.CUR.doNotLinkIt = 1
  2.CURIFSUB.doNotLinkIt = 1

  2.NO.wrapItemAndSub = <div class="layer2-col first">|</div>|*|<div class="layer2-col">|</div>|*|<div class="layer2-col last">|</div>
  2.NO.ATagParams = class="layer2"
  2.ACT.wrapItemAndSub = <div class="layer2-col first">|</div>|*|<div class="layer2-col">|</div>|*|<div class="layer2-col last">|</div>
  2.ACT.ATagParams = class="layer2 selected"
  2.IFSUB.wrapItemAndSub = <div class="layer2-col first">|</div>|*|<div class="layer2-col">|</div>|*|<div class="layer2-col last">|</div>
  2.IFSUB.ATagParams = class="layer2"
  2.CUR.wrapItemAndSub = <div class="layer2-col first">|</div>|*|<div class="layer2-col">|</div>|*|<div class="layer2-col last">|</div>
  2.CUR.ATagParams = class="layer2 selected"
  2.CURIFSUB.wrapItemAndSub = <div class="layer2-col first">|</div>|*|<div class="layer2-col">|</div>|*|<div class="layer2-col last">|</div>
  2.CURIFSUB.ATagParams = class="layer2 selected"
  2.NO.linkWrap = <span class="layer2-headline">|</span>
  3 < .1
  #3.NO.doNotLinkIt = 0
  3.wrap = <ul class="layer2-wrap">|</ul>
  3.NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
  3.NO.ATagParams =
  3.ACT.ATagParams = class="active"
  3.IFSUB.ATagParams =
  3.CUR.ATagParams = class="selected"
  3.CURIFSUB.ATagParams = class="selected"

  stdWrap.prepend.data = LLL:{$filepaths.l10n}:nav_top
}
```

and the defaults:

```
menu.defaults = HMENU
menu.defaults {
   1 = TMENU
   1 {
     wrap = <ul>|</ul>

     # Always unfold all sub-levels of the menu
     expAll = 0

     # Remove the (old) default behaviour which adds onfocus="blurLink(this);" to all links
     noBlur = 1

     # Define the normal state (not active, not selected) of menu items
     # Using NO=1 to activate normal state is not necessary, but useful when copying
     NO = 1
     NO {
       # Use the page title field the title property on the A-tag, but only if the navigation title is set
       ATagTitle {
         field = title
         fieldRequired = nav_title
       }

       # Use the option-split feature to generate a different wrap for the last item on a level of the menu
       # The last item on each level gets class="last" added for CSS styling purposes.
       #
       # See the TSref documentation for details about option split and other features:
       # http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/references/doc_core_tsref/current/
       #wrapItemAndSub = <li class="first">|</li> |*| <li>|</li> |*| <li class="last">|</li>
       wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>

       # HTML-encode special characters according to the PHP-function htmlSpecialChars
       stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
     }

     IFSUB = 1
     IFSUB < .NO
     IFSUB {
       wrapItemAndSub = <li class="subpages">|</li>
       ATagBeforeWrap = 1
     }

     # Copy properties of normal to active state, and then add a CSS class for styling
     ACT = 1
     ACT < .NO
     ACT {
       ATagParams = class="active"
     }

     # Copy properties of normal to current state, and then add a CSS class for styling
     CUR = 1
     CUR < .NO
     CUR {
       ATagParams = class="selected"
       #wrapItemAndSub = <li class="selected">|</li>
     }

     CURIFSUB < .IFSUB
     CURIFSUB {
       ATagParams = class="selected"
     }
   }
   2 < .1
   3 < .2
   stdWrap.prepend =< lib.srHint
 }
```

Is this somehow possible?

Comment: It seems to me that you are just guessing what those attributes do. **ATagBeforeWrap** - If set, the link is first wrapped with ".wrap" and then the <A>-tag. **wrapItemAndSub** - Wraps the whole item and any submenu concatenated to it. // Is *<sub></sub>* supposed to represent a submenu in your code? I suggest you include your whole menu code in the question.

Comment: Show us your TypoScript

Comment: That makes much more sense now and actually becomes and interesting question. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only way to do this is to use the `before.cObject = HMENU` and create a second menu based on the current value inside your wrap.

Comment: Thx for the answer. I will wait for some more educated feedback before I give credit, as I took an other approach for the related problem, the project is finished and Im not really able to judge your answer.